# Does anyone know how to use conditional statements inside image_tags in ruby on rails.

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements

Hello I am building a daily horoscope fortune telling app in ruby on rails. I am able to get the page to display a random image however I want a message to be associated with a certain picture when the user clicks on the button to tell their future. So far I have

```
<h1>What Does The Shadows Say About Your Heart</h1>
<%= image_tag "#{rand(21)}.jpg", size: "300x300"  %>
<% if image_tag "0.jpg", size: "300x300" %>
   <p>You have a thirst for vengeance.</p>
<% end %>
<% if image_tag "1.jpg" , size: "300x300"%>
   <p>Soon you will face a great adversary.</p>
<% end %>
<% if image_tag "2.jpg" , size: "300x300"%>
   <p>The road is not always clear.</p>
<% end %>
```

and my controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 def home
 end

 def show
   @dark = ["0" , "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",    "6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
 end
end
```

However the messages display on all the pictures. Please help it would be great. If you need to see more code just let me know. Note: I am not using carrierwave active admin nor paperclip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want

**Controller**

```
def show
  @random = rand(21)
end
```

**show.html**

```
<h1>What Does The Shadows Say About Your Heart</h1>
<%= image_tag "#{@random}.jpg", size: "300x300"  %>
<p><%= image_message(@random)%></p>
```

**page_helper.rb**

```
def image_message(random)
  message = {1=> 'You have a thirst for vengeance.', 2=> 'Soon you will face a great adversary.', 3=> 'The road is not always clear.'}
  message[random]
end
```

Comment: PERFECT!!! This is great Thank You. If possible could you tell me how you arrived at this answer.

Comment: I have seen your requirement and the helper was fulfilling your requirement so I applied this approach

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve but one thing is for sure: move the logic out of the view; it will allow you to be more flexible as well.

```
class ImageRandomizer
  MAPPING = [
    [0, 'Financial good'], [1, 'Love life awesome'],...
  ]
  def image
    random_image_mapping.first
  end

  def message
    random_image_mapping.last
  end

  private

  def random_image_mapping
    @random_image_mapping ||= MAPPING[rand(1..21)]
  end
end
```

*controller.rb*

```
def show
  @random_image = ImageRandomizer.new
end
```

*show.html.erb*

```
<h1>What Does The Shadows Say About Your Heart</h1>
<%= image_tag "#{@random_image.image}.jpg", size: "300x300"  %>
<p><%= @random_image.message %></p>
```

Comment: Just to be clear Would You Include The Class ImageRandomizer in the Show Controller. And Sorry It Took So Long To Respond.